# SQL Insert statement with auto-incrementing unique id

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table that stores a few values, one being an INT id, which is unique, and should increment by one for every new query, but I can't figure out how to process the query without providing a value.

Here's the SQL Query I'm using:

```
INSERT INTO db VALUES (0, $username, $score);
```

0 is what I have put in place of having it increment automatically. What should I put instead?

Comment: This (easily searchable "auto-increment" concept) is explained in no shortage of tutorials and documentation.

Comment: Use the zero or better simply omit that value completely. Read the documentation for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is just to leave it out:

```
INSERT INTO db(username, score) -- or whatever the columns are
    VALUES ($username, $score);
```

When using `INSERT`, you should always list the columns.  This is good for maintainability, readability, and debugging.

Comment: This worked; thank you very much! I should also note I had to check the A_I box in phpmyadmin (or add AUTO_INCREMENT after an ALTER TABLE query)

Comment: @WestonReed . . . Yes!  This does assume that the column is set for `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  The way I read your question, I thought that might already be the case.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be putting anything for `id` field. The database does it for itself. Think of it. So if you put `0` every time, that thing is going to be static isn't it? Therefore, you do not have to worry about that auto_increasing field. Your query shall be something like:

```
INSERT INTO db(username,score) VALUES($username, $score);
```